# How to delete only one object within a stringified JSON stored in Localstorage?

Tags: javascript, json

I am saving my products that belong to the shopping cart on the local storage. Everything has the same key. I am using the following code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i<produkt.length; i++) {
        .
        .
        .
  document.querySelector('a.produktlöschen'+[i]).addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    const parsed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('warenkorb'));
    parsed.splice(parsed.indexOf(i), 1);
    localStorage.setItem('warenkorb', JSON.stringify(parsed));
    location.reload();
```

the for loop is for the dynamic shopping cart. `product1` is `i=0`, `product2` is `i=1` ...
My plan is, when the Anchor is clicked, that the `product[I]` (depends on which Anchor) gets deleted.
With my code, only the last item gets deleted and not the one which anchor is clicked.

```
     let produkt = [
 {
  name: '3er Set Bambuszahnbürste',
  preis: 10,
  marke: 'LifePanda',
  seit: 2020,
  bild_url: '../img/Produkt_1.jpg',
  id: 1
},
{
name: 'Nachhaltiges Einkaufsnetz',
preis: 19,
marke: 'GreenEarth',
seit: 2019,
bild_url: '../img/Produkt_2.jpg',
id: 2
}];
```

Comment: When you click your i is already through the loop, take the sender object in the event handler to determine which project to remove.

Comment: use the same object Array for all products, also use event delegation for a clearer code

Comment: It is better if all the items are stored in an Array of Objects. When you remove an item remove it from the array and then store the Array into localStorage. Better than having to parse the stringed object and stringifies it again when there is a change into products(this consumes so much processing)

Comment: parsed.indexOf(i) is meaningless. It should be a bug

Comment: there is no number index in Objects it is not an array object.

Answer (score 0):

**Use an OBJECT**

You are having problems in referencing (getting the index of) the Array item you wanted to remove. A better way is to directly use an object instead of an Array. This way you can call them using the name you assigned them instead of finding a way to get the index of the item you wanted.

```
// Using an object you can just directly assign an id that you can call anytime
const obj = {}
obj['a12e'] = {...} // obj = {a12e:{...}}  // add new properties
obj.a12e.name = ... // change properties
delete obj.a12e = //delete properties
```

---

**Do not pull your data from the localStorage**

Also, it is better if all the items are stored in an Array of Objects or Objects (depends on your preference). That way, when you remove an item you can remove it from the array and then store the Array into localStorage. Better than having to parse the stringed object and stringifies it again when there is a change into products(this consumes so much time)

Let's compare the concepts then

> **Changing an Item directly from localStorage**:
>  0# onclick
> 1# get JSON from localStorage
>  2# parse JSON to Array
>  3# remove
> item from Array
>  4# convert Array to stringified JSON
>  5# store
> stringified JSON to localStorage
>
> **Changing an Item in an Array/object**:
>  0# onclick
>  1# remove item from Array/Object
>  2# convert Array/Object to stringified
> JSON
>  3# store stringified JSON to localStorage

Example

```
// HTML

<div class=item id=item0><span>Cheese cake </span><button class=remove>x</button></div>
<div class=item id=item1><span>Chocolate cake </span><button class=remove>x</button></div>
<div class=item id=item2><span>Strawberry cake </span><button class=remove>x</button></div>
<div class=item id=item3><span>Double Chocolate cake </span><button class=remove>x</button></div>

// JavaScript

const productItemsObject = {}

localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(productItemsObject))

for (let items of document.querySelectorAll('.item')) {

  productItemsObject[items.id]={name: items.children[0].innerText} // store everything in an object
  
  items.children[1] /*button*/ .addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    //Using an Object
    delete productItemsObject[items.id] // remove item from array
    localStorage.setItem('productsObj', JSON.stringify(productItemsObject)) // update the data in localStorage only after every change
    
    items.remove()
    
    console.log("Object",localStorage.productsObj)
  })
}
```